# Pattern to manage many sql dialects - "WITH UR" IN ORACLE 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, db2

I'm trying to make a porting from DB2 to ORACLE 11g and in order to do this I've to change the code of my application (avoiding to rewrite the whole application). The statement "WITH UR" (with Uncommitted Read) doesn't works
with ORACLE beacuse  it doesn't support dirty reads. Is there an elegant and simple way or a pattern to do this avoiding to put in my code an "IF" with a property set in a file (dirty solution)?

```
@Override
public List<Object[]> receiptSummary(String idENTITY) {

    List<Object[]> listObj = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

    try {

        StringBuilder sqlQuery = new StringBuilder();
        sqlQuery.append("SELECT TE.DE_TRB AS TYPE_DEBT, COUNT(*) AS NUM_RECEIPTS, SUM(BBR.AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT ")
                .append("FROM DRAFTS_TRANSFERS_CREDITING BBR, TRANSFERS_CREDITING BR, LISTS_CREDITING DR, CONDITIONS C, PAYINGS TE ")
                .append("WHERE ");

        if (idENTITY != null && !idENTITY.isEmpty()) {
            sqlQuery.append("BBR.ID_ENTITY = :id_ENTITY AND ");
        }

        sqlQuery.append("BBR.ID_TRANSFERS_CREDITING=BR.ID ")
                .append("AND BR.ID_LISTS_CREDITING = DR.ID ")
                .append("AND C.ID_CONDITION = BBR.ID_CONDITION ")
                .append("AND DR.STATE='DONE' ")
                .append("AND TE.CD_TRB_ENTITY = C.CD_TRB_ENTITY ")
                .append("GROUP BY TE.DE_TRB ")
                .append("WITH UR"); //FIXME: FOR ORACLE

        Query q = em.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery.toString());

        if (idENTITY != null && !idENTITY.isEmpty()) {
            q.setParameter("id_ENTITY", idENTITY);
        }

        String msg = "DAO - receiptSummary - id_ENTITY:" + idENTITY;

        if (Tracer.isDebugEnabled(this.getClass().getName())) {
            Tracer.debug(this.getClass().getName(), "receiptSummary", msg);
            Tracer.debug(this.getClass().getName(), "receiptSummary", sqlQuery.toString());
        }

        System.out.println("receiptSummary - " + msg);
        System.out.println("receiptSummary - " +  sqlQuery.toString());

        listObj = (List<Object[]>) q.getResultList();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Tracer.error(this.getClass().getName(), "receiptSummary", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return listObj;
}
```

Comment: You don't need "WITH UR" in Oracle. Just leave it out.

Comment: I know, but I want that my JAVA code works with DB2 and ORACLE.

Comment: Then change the isolation level on the connection before running the statement using `Connection.setIsolationLevel()`. That way you can remove the non-standard options from the SQL. But this won't be the only place where you have different syntax. You *will* have different SQL for different DBMS if you want to use each DBMS efficiently.

Comment: Can I use Query.setLockMode(LockModeType lockMode) in JPA 2 in order to set Uncommitted Read? Is there any way to do this with JPA?